# app.config globalization

Tags: .net, visual-studio, globalization, application-settings

web.config allow a globalization tag:

This setting will set the globalization for the entire ASP.NET application.

Does this tag work in app.config in standard forms applications too?
If yes... where shall it be placed?

---

Or.. is there another way to set the globalization for the entire forms application. Including dll's and all threads?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104084/how-do-i-set-cultureinfo-currentculture-from-an-app-config-file

Answer (score 4):

take a look at the following topic:
  [How to: Set the Culture and UI Culture for Windows Forms Globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b28bx3bh%28VS.80%29.aspx)

To set the Culture to the Main Application use the following snippet code:

```
Dim newCulture As CultureInfo = new CultureInfo("fr-FR")
CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture
```

Comment: Thanks, But is there no way to set it for all threads in the application?

Comment: I don't think so, however if you are creating the threads in your application you can set the culture for everyone by yourself.