# Is it possible to set the globalization culture in a windows services config file?

Tags: c#, windows-services, app-config

I am developing a windows-service and would like to setup the culture in my app.config file.
Is it possible?
If yes where should I put the parameter?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104084/how-do-i-set-cultureinfo-currentculture-from-an-app-config-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in way of configuring this, but you can add an appSetting and configure your thread's culture at start up.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265556/app-config-globalization) should help.