# Why is my EXE not using the correct cultureinfo

Tags: c#, winforms

My forms have `resx` files for Hebrew which I generate by changing the `Localizable` property to  `true` and then translating all the control captions.

However, when I run the application either in the debugger or as a release version, it uses the English values from the default `resx` file.

My computer has both `CultureInfo` and `CultureUIInfo` set to `he-IL`, should it not be detecting that and automatically using the correct resource values?

Do I have to set something else to make this work?

Comment: Have you checked what `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` returns while you're running the app? Have you deployed the appropriate satellite assemblies containing the localized resources?

Comment: Also, make sure you are not setting English as the default language in your app.config: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104084/how-do-i-set-cultureinfo-currentculture-from-an-app-config-file

Comment: I checked and am getting `he-IL`

Comment: @Jon Skeet: If I understand your second question correctly, in the runtime folder, I have a folder named `he-IL` which contains [name of app].resources.dll Should that not be enough for the application to use Hebrew when the CultureUIInfo is Hebrew?

Comment: Yes, that should be enough. That's surprising...