# C# DateTime.Parse ignores CultureInfo

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

Work in Australia and have received message from US that `DateTime` is parsing string **"Dec15"** wrongly and returning **Dec 15, 2016** instead of **Dec 1, 2015**.  "Dec15" in snippets below are variables in real life.

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("Dec15", new CultureInfo("en-AU")); //returns December 1 2015
```

I can not replicate even after changing my PC Formats & Location to point to US.

However, I can replicate if I change the code to use a US culture.

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("Dec15", new CultureInfo("en-US")); //returns December 15 2016
```

I'm not aware the code has been a problem in the past.  I would like some help understanding why the `CultureInfo` is being ignored/replaced with what appears to be there default Cultures over there in the US.

Appreciate any suggestions you may have.

Comment: I'm in Australia, and `DateTime.Parse("Dec15")` is indeed returning the 1st of December 2015, and not 15th December, so I think the fact they're in Australia is a red herring, and it's another issue at play

Comment: Dec15 is indeed 2016-12-01... There is no way to fix that for single app with config as far as I know (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104084/how-do-i-set-cultureinfo-currentculture-from-an-app-config-file) - but if you can't fix your broken date parsing you can ask your users to change region to whatever you like...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Dec15` isn't a standard DateTime format, my guess is the parser doesn't recognise it regardless of the culture provided.

In order to parse it correctly, you can use the `ParseExact` method to provide a format to use:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("Dec15", "MMMyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

That then provides you a `DateTime` object to further parse as you need to.

Comment: Yes a more robust solution but would require a new release.  I'm hoping there is something on the client side that may fix this.

Answer (score 2):

It all works fine, and as you can see the culture is not ignored, because you have to manually specify CultureInfo to get the desired wrong result.

I am 100% sure that if you will look at `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` you will see different results in the machine in Australia and US

The parsing is always using CurrentCulture. If you want want to have fixed format just use `DateTime.ParseExact` method.

Or you can force the Culture for application [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468791/is-there-a-way-of-setting-culture-for-a-whole-application-all-current-threads-a)

Also you may want to look at [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/global_developer/2011/01/24/exploring-windows-locales-and-net-cultures/)

Comment: but shouldn't passing in CultureInfo class to Parse method of datetime, should overwrite for that method call?

Comment: Yes, it should. But from my understanding the original code uses one argument overload of the method

Comment: Original code is first snippet and I expected it to use the "en-AU" culture date formatting