# Float.Parse() ignoring decimal comma

Tags: c#, parsing, floating-point

I am getting some percent values from a database and I need to format them to have the correct thousands seperator, number of decimal places and a percent sign on the end.

I tried this:

```
string text = "105,3"; //example, formatting like database input
string format = "#,##0.##";

e.Row.Cells[i].Text = double.Parse(text).ToString(format);
```

Weirdly this returns `1053,00%`. How do I make it so it returns `105,30%`? (The decimal comma is because the system locale is german, so it's how it is supposed to be)

edit: replacing the comma with a period results in `10530.00%`. Nothing makes sense to me anymore.

edit2: the `float.Parse()` actually works just fine. the `ToString()` messes everything up. I played around with using different cultural settings and format strings (switching comma and period) but it only makes it worse again.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this (tried using `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE");`) - I get `105,3`

Comment: Same here, used your code and got the correct result.

Comment: @MatthewWatson didn't work for me, neither with `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` nor with `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE")`

Comment: I suspect this must be to do with some formatting used for `e.Row.Cells[i]` and nothing to do with the value returned from `double.Parse(text).ToString(format);`

Comment: try to store result of parsing to string - you could check then if there is a problem with parse method (suppose not);
And then try to assign to Cell[i] custom string, for example "105,30"- I think there would be a problem. Maybe with your UI culture setting

Comment: maybe check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9104557/5358389

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title is misleading. The actual problem was the `ToString()` function. In the format string I added the `%` sign, which, to be fair, I didn't add in the original post because I forgot about it. It automatically multiplies the number by 100. So my format string is now `"#,##0.00\%"`.

Answer (score 3):

Pass the current Culture to the `Parse` method: `double.Parse( text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture )`

However, this only works on systems that use a locale that has the comma as a decimal separator.
If you want this to work on other locales you should replace `CurrentCulture` with the specific CultureInfo instance that used when inputting data in the first place.

Comment: there is no overload that takes cultureinfo as parameter, do you know of another function that does?

Comment: Yes there is: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ebt447(v=vs.110).aspx (CultureInfo implements the IFormatProvider interface)

Comment: you're right, it takes it as a parameter. sadly it still outputs it the same way, even with german culture hardcoded

Comment: Did you make sure that the result of the Parse and ToString calls are correct? If so the problem is probably that the DataGrid is using a wrong culture to format the passed value.

Comment: by now I figured out that the actual problem is the `ToString()`. It messes it  whether I use a comma or a period as decimal seperator