# ILogger displays incorrect currency Symbol

Tags: c#, .net-core, cultureinfo

When I try to output a numeric value with the currency format specifier using `ILogger.LogInformation()` I get an unexpected symbol different from when I use `Console.Log(string.Format())`.  The later displays the expected dollar sign as the symbol where as the former displays something unprintable.

**Sample Code**

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddLogging(x =>
{
    x.AddDebug();
    x.AddConsole();
});
var svcProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var logger = svcProvider.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory().CreateLogger<Program>();
logger.LogInformation("Amount {0:C}", 100.0);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Amount {0:C}", 100.0));
```

**Output from Debug**

> xyz.Program:Information: Amount ¤100.00
>
> Amount $100.00

I see know way of configuring CultureInfo for the ILogger and I don't want to specify it each time I write.  Also, I don't think this is relevant, but the code is being executed inside an `async` method.

So is this a bug, are my expectations unrealistic, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Maybe [How do I set CultureInfo.CurrentCulture from an App.Config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50856078/205233) helps.

Comment: FYI, that unprintable character is called "scarab":  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_sign_(typography)

Comment: No dice @Filburt, thanks.

Comment: Why not create a wrapping function to the logger that specifies the culture?

Comment: `ILogger` is just the interface. Localization should be set during configuration. The built-in logger has limited functionality but in *this* case I'd have to ask *why do that*? It's highly unlikely that the application will only handle *one* currency. If there's an implied currency, it *shouldn't* appear in the logs anyway to avoid causing confusion

Comment: IMO printing that symbol is the correct behavior.  Your logs shouldn't depend on the users current culture.  `¤` denotes a currency.

Comment: @DanielGimenez explain why you want to do what you try to do here first. `LogInformation` formats the message on the spot, then logs it. If you wanted something different, use a different provider, like Serilog. The *currency* though is business information that can't be implied

Comment: @DanielGimenez `LogInformation` uses the `InvariantCulture` unless you specify something else. In most cases logs shouldn't be affected by locale. `1.4.ToString("C",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` returns `¤1.40`. `ToString()` though uses the current culture which is affected by the server's locale and/or configuration settings. In my case `1.4.ToString("C")` returns `1,40 €`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if there is no way to specify culture in the logger factory or logger then it seems as though you commented all the components to the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently the reason for this behavior is that logs shouldn't be specific to any locale. I searched for a work around or setting in the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions repo, but there appears no way to circumvent this behavior.

(Almost) all of the logging methods for an *ILogger* come from a static extensions class, *LoggerExtensions* (*ILogger* defines one `Log` method which would be a pain to use directly).  All of the methods in that class end up calling the same `Log` method that converts the message format and its arguments into a *FormattedLogValues* object.

The *FormattedLogValues* object has a static cache keyed by the format string with the values of *LogValuesFormatter*.  These formatters are responsible for converting the message and args into a string and they explicitly set the culture to *CultureInfo.InvariantCulture* when calling `string.Format`.  This is why the "scarab" symbol (¤) is displayed when using the currency format specifier.

Since I know all of my amounts are going to be in dollars, the simplest and most correct solution was to eschew the currency specifier for a customer numeric format string.

```
logger.LogInformation("Amount {0:$#,##0.00}", 100.0);
```

*Thanks to @Amy and @PanagiotisKanavos for all of their help.*