# Set Application Language in App.Config

Tags: c#, winforms, globalization

I'd like to set in the App.Config either "en-US" or "ru-RU" to tell the app which resx it should use.
I don't want to let the app choose it automatically by the operating system's (envoirnment) language.

how would you do?

Comment: This is a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265556/app-config-globalization

Comment: I would let application decide which language to use, for it is one of i18n best practices.

Comment: got it, but let the app decide is for russian who mostly use english-OS not the best option.

Answer (score 0):

I simply use

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
```

in  `Program.cs` `Main()`-function.